# Как сделать indexOf Только по первому символу?

Tags: jquery, index, html, javascript

имеется две строки

> {$name}
>
> $1name

если сделать обычный indexOf по $  то результат будет всегда положительный. но необходимо чтобы indexOf работал только по первому символу? и срабатывал только на строки где $ самый первый

Comment: indexOf возвращает позицию. Так как Вам нужно, что бы только в первой позиции - проверяйте на равенство 0. Правда там в начале могут быть пробелы и я не знаю, как нужно в этом случае. Возможно поможет какой-нибудь trim. Или просто регулярка вида

    '\s*\$'

Comment: @KoVadim там не будет пробелов)
    var str="$";
    var prel="$1name";

    if(prel.indexOf(str)=0){
    первый символ=$}?
    так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Анатолийй](/users/4380/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%B9)](/users/4380/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%B9), не путайте оператор присваивания (=) с операторами сравнения (==, ===, > и т.д.).

```
if (pre1.indexOf(str) === 0) {
  // first char
}
```

А если регулярку использовать, то, имхо, красивее получается:

```
if (/^\$/.test(str)) {
   // first char
}
```